# Не работает проверка на http и https

Tags: javascript

На странице есть две кнопки. При клике на первую кнопку просим пользователя ввести в prompt ссылку, при клике на вторую - переадресовывается на другой сайт (по ранее введенной ссылке). Реализовать проверку на http / https. Если протокол не указан - добавляем. Вроде все правильно сделал,но проверка не работает

```js
const btnGetLink = document.getElementById('btnPrompt');
const btnGoToLink = document.getElementById('btnLink');
let link;
let linkArr;
let stringLink;

btnGetLink.onclick = function() {
    link = prompt("Write link");
    linkArr = link.split("");
    let arrText = [];
    const checkHttp = ['h','t','t','p'];
    const checkHttps = ['h','t','t','p','s'];

    for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        arrText.push(linkArr[i]);
    }

    if(arrText != checkHttp || arrText != checkHttps) {
        linkArr.unshift('h','t','t','p','s',':','/','/');
    }

    stringLink = linkArr.join("");
    console.log(stringLink);
}

btnGoToLink.onclick = function() {
    location.href = stringLink;
}
```

Comment: Боже, с какого языка вы это притащили?
По теме: массивы сравниваются по ссылке и очевидно `arrText` не равен `checkHttp`

Comment: И вообще это пишется в одну строчку `if (!/^https?:/.test(link)) { link = 'https://' + link; }`

Comment: @AlexeyTen в плане с какого языка? Это типичный JS или Python код.

Comment: @zerxa проверять строку «побайтово» это вообще ни разу не типичный JS или Python. Больше на хардкорный Си похоже…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const btnGetLink = document.getElementById('btnPrompt');
const btnGoToLink = document.getElementById('btnLink');
let link;
let linkArr;
let stringLink;

btnGetLink.onclick = function() {
    link = prompt("Write link");
    linkArr = link.split("");
    let arrText = [];
    const checkHttp = ['h','t','t','p'];
    const checkHttps = ['h','t','t','p','s'];

    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arrText.push(linkArr[i]);
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < arrText.length; i++) {
        if(arrText[i] === checkHttps[i] || arrText[i] === checkHttp[i]) {
            continue
        } else {
            linkArr.unshift('h','t','t','p','s',':','/','/');
            break
        }
    }

    stringLink = linkArr.join("");
    console.log(stringLink);
}

btnGoToLink.onclick = function() {
    location.href = stringLink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let btnGetLink = document.querySelector(".btnPrompt");
let btnGoTolLink = document.querySelector(".btnLink");
let link;

btnGetLink.addEventListener('click', function () {
    link = prompt("Введите ссылку");
    if (link.startsWith('http') === false && link.startsWith('https') === false) {
        link = `https://${link}`;
    }
})


btnGoTolLink.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (!link) {
        alert('Нет ссылки');
    } else {
        location.href = link;
    }
})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]